Character encoding issue in Java Spring emails displayed incorrectly in Outlook
I'm encountering an issue with character encoding in Java Spring when sending emails. The emails are displaying correctly in Gmail and iCloud, but when viewed in Outlook, special characters such as "é" are replaced with strange characters like "�". I suspect this is a character encoding problem specific to Outlook.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using to send emails:
MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setTo("recipient@example.com");
helper.setSubject("Subject with é character");
String htmlContent = "<html><body>Special characters like é are not displayed correctly in Outlook.</body></html>";
helper.setText(htmlContent, true);
emailSender.send(message);

I've ensured that the character encoding is set to UTF-8 both in the email template and in the Java Spring code. However, the issue persists only in Outlook.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem with character encoding in Java Spring emails displayed in Outlook? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried to use the HTML entity &#233; instead?
